# how does ITSM categorize suggestions?

Tags: itil

how does ITSM process a suggestion from a client? E.g., client suggests improvement in IT infrastructure.

I have already tried reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

ITIL / ITSM is a framework, so it will not give you definitive guidance on how to do this.  The answer is you document your own process, then refine it as time goes by.  The first implementation is liable be scrapped after the first use: be prepared to be flexible.

What I did was use a collaboration tool (Innovation Central) to log the customer suggestions.  There could be viewed and collaborated on by interested parties within the company.  The Product Manager would select feature requests as fitted the road-map and other development priorities.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to have a well-defined process for tracking enhancements/improvements/ideas and follow it consistently. Pre-built integration within the standard process and tool is extremely important in my opinion. A good tool like BMC Helix ITSM allows no-code application development and offers a variety of choices in leveraging OOTB artifacts to quickly assemble an app for such a purpose. To build such integration with an external tool, BMC offers pre-packaged solutions like-

https://www.bmc.com/blogs/enjoying-seamless-service-management-in-a-multi-cloud-multi-provider-world/